# Set textarea to pristine after submit in React

Tags: reactjs, textarea

In my React component there is a `required` textarea that shouldn't submit empty. After submit I stay within the same component so the textarea has red borders to indicate its errored state.

```
const CommentForm = ({ postId, addComment }) => {
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const onSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    addComment(postId, text);
    setText('');
};

const onChange = evt => {
    setText(evt.target.value)
};

return (
    <div className='post-form'>
        <div className='bg-primary p'>
            <h3>Add a Comment</h3>
        </div>
        <form className='form my-1' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <textarea
                name='text'
                placeholder='Comment on this post...'
                required
                value={text}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <input type='submit' className='btn btn-dark my-1' value='Submit' />
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

};

How do I remove the red borders after submitting a non empty value? The complete component code is at https://github.com/ElAnonimo/leansquad/blob/master/src/components/post/CommentForm.js.

Comment: do you have code to move to other page after submitting?

Comment: No. This is a comments page that displays a list of comments to a post. After a new comment submit the user stays on the page to see the new comment.

Comment: And where is the code of parent of CommentForm component. From where CommentForm is called.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/ElAnonimo/leansquad/blob/master/src/components/post/Post.js/ The only prop `CommentForm ` receives is `postId`.